# How to change value of object attribute on some condition

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object like this.

```
Obj : {
    USA : true
    NZ : false,
    Canada : true,
    Japan : false,
    China : true
    Ind : false,
}
```

In my function I am getting  `countery.name = IND` so on this condition how can I change the flag of respective country.

What I am trying on this here is

```
var countryName = countery.name // Getting some value here.
Object.keys(obj).map(function(i) {
    /*if(countryName == obj.countryName){ // something missing here
        obj.countryName.value 
    }*/
});
```

Comment: what is the expected output? Your question is not clear

Comment: *how can I change the flag* - change to what?

Comment: @brk `if(countryName  : IND)` then in object value wil change to true

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest change to true or false. Opsite to current value

Comment: why not use the same case for the keys as the requested country? otherwise the structure with keys makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> change to true or false. Opsite to current value

The solution using `Object.keys` function:

```js
var Obj = {USA : true,NZ : false,Canada : true,Japan : false,China : true,Ind : false},
    keys = Object.keys(Obj),
    len = keys.length,
    countryName = 'IND';

while (len--) {
    if (keys[len].toLowerCase() == countryName.toLowerCase()) {
        Obj[keys[len]] = !Obj[keys[len]];
        break;    // avoiding redundant iterations
    }
}

console.log(Obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the properties of the object via `Object.keys()` and then use `some()` to iterate over properties `toLowerCase()` function to compare property and the country name. In `if` statement use `return true` to break the loop if the key is found.

```js
var obj = {
    USA: true,
    NZ: false,
    Canada: true,
    Japan: false,
    China: true,
    Ind: false
};

var country = {
  name: 'IND'
};

Object.keys(obj).some(key => {
  if(key.toLowerCase() === country.name.toLowerCase()){    
    obj[key] = !obj[key];
    return true;
  }
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and exit the loop if found.

```js
var obj = { USA: true, NZ: false, Canada: true, Japan: false, China: true, Ind: false },
    countryName = 'IND';

Object.keys(obj).some(function (k) {
    if (k.toLowerCase() === countryName.toLowerCase()) {
        obj[k] = !obj[k];
        return true;
    }
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the object's property like `obj[countryName] = !obj[countryName].value` when the condition passes.

```
obj = {USA:true, NZ: false, Canada:true,Japan:false,China:true,Ind:false}; 
var countryName = 'Ind';

console.log("Before changing the flag:");
console.log(obj);

Object.keys(obj).map(function(i){ 
if (countryName == i)
    obj[countryName] = !obj[countryName].value;
});

console.log("After changing the flag:");
console.log(obj);
```